# Login into SAP using admin user fails

Tags: sap-basis

My SAP installation has created a user sapuser, and I am able to login into ABAP Workbench with user:

- sapuser/password (user:800)

I am also able to login using the following credentials:

- SAP*/PASS (user:800)

However, I am not able to login using the following credentials, why?

1. eccadm/password (user:800)
2. DDIC/19920706 (user:000,001)
3. EARLYWATCH/support (user:066)

I played with DDIC and the logs show:

> Password logon no longer possible - too many failed attempts.

Also in TCODE `su01` when I enter `DDIC` user, SAP says:

> User DDIC does not exist.

Also when I login through SAPUSER or SAP* and check `usr02` table in `se16`, I see only SAPUSER user created by SAP*:

[image]

Comment: Referred to logs at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eccadm is an OS user, that's why you can't login to SAP system with it. Use SAP* or DDIC for initial login in your productive client and then create user accounts.
DDIC password should be your MASTER password, created during installation of the system.
EARLYWATCH user is available only in client 066 per default.